# AngularJS flip and grow div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm new to Angular/CSS and I've been checking out some stuff about how to flip a card and how to apply different rotations and animations. I've both flavours where you can flip on hover over and flip on click. I have my new ng-app that has a controller that toggles a css class for flipping a div and all of that works fine. However what I would like to achieve would be something like that:

http://jsfiddle.net/jwhazel/AaU6v/11/

Which is in JQuery and honestly I don't know how best it would translate into the Angular world. I have started creating a directive that tries that but I'm kind of stuck. Basically all I've got is the link function that binds the element click which is my card but I can't even get access to the position of the element.

```js
link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            element.bind('click', function(){
```

And for now I'm logging some stuff to proof is getting there which it does. But things like offset() or getBoundingClientRec don't work. I'm using Angular 1.4.0.

Any tips are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Carlos.